# AutoComplete for a WPF editable ComboBox including Separator control shows System.Windows.Controls.Separator

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, separator

AutoComplete for a WPF editable ComboBox including Separator control shows System.Windows.Controls.Separator.

With this xaml:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="true">
   <ComboBoxItem Content="aaaaa"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="bbbbb"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="ccccc"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Users can started typing with a to c, to auto complete the rest of characters.
a will become aaaaa, b will become bbbbb and so on.

However, the problem is if I want to add separator and make some of them exempting from auto-completion.
I tried this one:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="true">
   <ComboBoxItem Content="aaaaa"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="bbbbb"/>
   <Separator IsEnabled="false"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="ccccc" IsEnabled="false"/>
</ComboBox>
```

When I hit c, combobox still show ccccc as choice. 
Also, when I hit S, weirdly the combobox shows System.Windows.Controls.Separator as a choice(!)

My expectation was auto complete only supports typing a and b since the other two (Separator and ccccc) is set to IsEnabled="false".

Is there any solution for this?
Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the items collection to introduce something which looks like a header is probably not such a good idea, you will run into all kinds of problems including this one. You might be better of creating a custom `Template` for the `ComboBox` or a custom control altogether which provides properties for this functionality.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, one thing I made a mistake is that I wrote as "Header", but I meant "Content" in the xaml.  Does it affect to your answer?  At any rate, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Aki24x: No, it does not, i noticed that already when i tried your code.

Comment: I see.  So, basically I should not include something which does not belong to ComboBox such as Separator.  I'll think about writing custom Template.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer for future visitors: I ran into this issue today and do not want to go through all the work of creating a custom template as the accepted answer proposes.

For me, the list is very limited so I set the `TextSearch.Text` attached property for the `Separator` to a character which is unlikely to ever be typed. Here I use the Copyright symbol:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="true">
 <ComboBoxItem Content="aaaaa"/>
 <ComboBoxItem Content="bbbbb"/>
 <Separator IsEnabled="false" TextSearch.Text="&#xA9;"/>
 <ComboBoxItem Content="ccccc" IsEnabled="false"/>
</ComboBox>
```